# XML file not being included in one-click application using Visual Studio Express 2012

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2012, include, clickonce

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction...

I have a solution, to which I added an XML file.  The XML file contains a list of values used to populate a comboBox. It needs to be able to be edited by a technician when those values need to be updated.

The problem is that the XML file is not being included in the application when installed on the client system.  I can see the file.XML.deploy in the application installer files, but it does not get installed which causes the application to crash.  I can manually copy the file and it works, but why doesn't the installer install this file?

In Visual studio, for properties, I have "Build Action" set to "content" and "Copy to Output Directory" set to "copy always".
What else am I missing?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I was able to figure it out...
I had to click on "application files" in the publish section of the solution properties and change the "publish status" from "Data file (auto)" to "include".  Even though "download group" was set to "required", the file still wasn't being installed until I change the "publish status" setting...